# Selectively disable JSF resource dependencies

Tags: jsf, resources, bootsfaces, butterfaces

If I use both bootsfaces and butterfaces in a single page, both libraries import their bundled jquery and bootstrap stylesheet as belows:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/javax.faces.resource/bootstrap.min.css.xhtml?ln=butterfaces-configurable">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/javax.faces.resource/css/bootstrap.min.css.xhtml?ln=bsf">

<script type="text/javascript" src="javax.faces.resource/jquery.min.js.xhtml?ln=butterfaces-configurable"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javax.faces.resource/jquery.min.js.xhtml?ln=bsf"></script>
```

If both libraries use the same version , it waste bandwidth to import duplicate things. If both libraries use different versions , it is possible to have conflict. What is the best approach to deal with this? Can I selectively disable one component libraries to import certain stylesheets or scripts ?

Comment: Do you happen to use OmniFaces?

Comment: Yes. I use Omnifaces . Do you mean to use CombinedResourceHandler? How about how to deal with the version conflict ?

Comment: With CombinedResourceHandler you can indeed suppress resources via web.xml or even via a master XHTML template. But without it, there are other ways too, it only requires a bit of custom code.

Comment: @KenChan (OT, but only slightly) You're the first person I know using both BootsFaces and ButterFaces - something I believed to be impossible because the two frameworks are so similar. Would you mind to contact me to report about your experiences?

Comment: @Stephan . No problem. The reason I use ButterFaces is because I want to use its boostrap datetime picker. If BootsFaces also provides the boostrap datetime picker , then I don't need to use ButterFaces . Perhaps , I should open a ticket to request Bootfaces to have   boostrap datetime picker too :P Finally , thanks for open source BootsFaces :D

Comment: @KenChan You don't need to open a ticket - there already is one :). Please vote for [the time picker issue in our bug tracker](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/144) (by leaving a comment).

Answer (score 3):

you can use following web.xml parameter to disable providing jQuery in #ButterFaces.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>de.larmic.butterfaces.provideJQuery</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

you can likewise disable bootstrap if you have your own version

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>de.larmic.butterfaces.provideBootstrap</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: That's a nice alternative. Are you the author of ButterFaces?

Comment: Yes, I'm one the creators of ButterFaces. Are you working on BootsFaces?

Comment: Yes, I am :). It would be nice to get in contact. Maybe our teams could help each other.

Answer (score 1):

**Update January 22, 2016**: In the meantime, we (the BootsFaces team) went into some lengths to add fine-grained control over the resource loading. See http://www.bootsfaces.net/layout/resourcemanagement.jsf for details. Cutting a long story short, BootsFaces doesn't load jQuery, jQueryUI or Bootstrap if it detects these resources are already there. Plus, you can deactivate resource loading by an web.xml context parameters.

Outdated original answer:
Currently, the only solution is to use OmniFaces, like BalusC said. We could offer to improve BootsFaces so that it adds jQuery.min.js and bootstrap.min.css only if these libraries aren't provided by the JSF page. In this case, ButterFaces would provide jQuery and BootsFaces. Of course, you'd be responsible to make sure that the jQuery version provided is compatible to BootsFaces.